# PowerShell Core in Debian Docker Container Error

Tags: powershell, docker, debian, dockerfile, powershell-core

I'm new to Docker and am trying to create a Docker image with Raspbian base and PowerShell Core installed.

**EDIT:** Updated Dockerfile to include `libicu52` package, which resolved the main error: lack of `libpsl-native` or dependencies not available. Changed `CMD` parameters and now have a different error.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Download the latest RPi3 Debian image
FROM resin/raspberrypi3-debian:latest

# Update the image and install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get  install -y \
    wget \
    libicu52 \
    libunwind8 \
    && apt-get clean

# Grab the latest tar.gz
RUN wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-rc.2/powershell-6.0.0-rc.2-linux-arm32.tar.gz

# Make folder to put PowerShell
RUN mkdir ~/powershell

# Unpack the tar.gz file
RUN tar -xvf ./powershell-6.0.0-rc.2-linux-arm32.tar.gz -C ~/powershell

# Run PowerShell
CMD pwsh -v
```

New error:

```
hostname: you must be root to change the host name
/bin/sh: 1: pwsh: not found
```

How do I resolve these errors?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading from source and extracting it in your container, I'd recommend using the official `apt` installer packages for your Dockerfile from [Microsoft's official Debian repository](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod/) as described at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-macos-and-linux?view=powershell-6#debian-9

So transforming that to Dockerfile format:

```
# Install powershell related system components
RUN apt-get install -y \
    gnupg curl apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get clean

# Import the public repository GPG keys
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Register the Microsoft's Debian repository
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list'

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    powershell

# Start PowerShell
CMD pwsh
```

Alternatively you can also try to start from one of the original Microsoft docker Linux images, but of course then you need to solve then the raspberry installation for yourself:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/powershell/tags/

Comment: I tried using the method suggested, though I did change it to debian-8 as the base image was still Jessie. However, it was unable to find the powershell package when I used the code provided by Microsoft.

Comment: More importantly though, all the files from the Microsoft repository are for x64 architectures, not armhf, which prevents any of them being used as part of an rpi image.